# TeXShop does not compile on Mac OS El Capitan (pdflatex not found)

Tags: errors, texshop, mac

I am having trouble typesetting with TeXShop (using the latest 2015 version for Mac) in OS X El Capitan.

When I try I get the following error message:

> Library/TeX/texbin /Library/TeX/texbin /Library/TeX/texbin
>   /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end
>   for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a
>   distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade.
>   If so, go to http://tug.org/MacTeX and follow the instructions to
>   (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is
>   incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you
>   are using the macports or fink distributions.

I have read many posts related to the same problem but non has helped me so far. I tried reinstalling, I made sure the correct path /Library/TeX/texbin was input in the preferences, I even tried to replace it with /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin (where the texbin link leads to from /Library/TeX and where I can see the pdflatex file is). None of this was successful. For instance if I try with the other directory I get:

> /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin
>   /Library/TeX/texbin
>   /Library/TeX/texbin
>   /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://tug.org/MacTeX and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions.

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered same problem, and reinstalled Texlive, then everything goes fine.

Comment: I updated TexLive and reinstalled the pdftex files using it, now it works! Thank you very much!!